# Spurious files in my application's data directory

Tags: android, android-activity, samsung-mobile, datadirectory

I recently added a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 to my device collection.  I have an app that stores data files in its "home" directory, and I notice that this particular device keeps creating extraneous files in that directory.  I've been running on other Samsung devices for a couple of years and have not seen this before.  I can delete the files, but they will be automatically recreated at some point and show up the next time my app starts.

The files are all named like "rList-com.[company].[module].[submodule].[application].[Activity name]".  I see several of these, each corresponding to a different activity in my application.  Which files are there varies, probably in conjunction with which of the application activities have run.

What are these files?  Is there a way I can make them go away (and never come back)?  Is Samsung doing this?  Verizon?  Android?

(The phone is running 4.4.1, but I also have a tablet running 4.4.1, also from Samsung, that doesn't do this.)

Comment: same problem here; did you find out why these files were there?

Comment: No.  I did find other posts on SO that recommended against storing files in an application's root directory, or at least assuming that the only files you would find there were files you put there.  I released a new version of the app that moves the existing data files to a new subdirectory and manages them there.  That seems to be working fine.